# Select more attractors in anylogic contemporary

Tags: anylogic

I need to put all the attractors of rectangular node in an collection.I don't want to do it manually, but i don't find any other solution. Help?Thanks
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNB77.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dynamic solution that will not need to be updated manually in case you add more attractors to a node at a later stage

[image]

You can get all the attractors of a space markup element by simply calling getAttractors().

The AnyLogic collection element expects an array as an input so we need to convert the list to an array using `.toArray()`

You can also initialise it in some other code using
`collection = node.getAttractors()`

Answer (score 1):

simple... go to the project panel and select all of them as shown in the following image... then click on create collection

[image]